# A function to split long rows into shorter rows in google spreadsheets?

Tags: forms, function, split, rows, google-sheets

I have a Google spreadsheet that receives data from a form. Every answer in this form results in a 224 column long row in my spreadsheet.

What I need is a function that splits every one of these rows into several rows, each containing only 7 columns.

This is a live form that will continue adding more lines the spreadsheet. Thus I need a formula that:

1. Splits a row into several rows.
2. Does this for every row from the form without overwriting itself.
3. Automatically does this for every new row of data that is received.

As I have tried to achieve this seemingly simple thing for several hours without success i now ask the internet for help. I would be so grateful if someone can help me with this.

Answer (score 0):

I doubt a regular spreadsheet formulas composition will do it. You'll need Google Apps Script, please read the [guide](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guide) and [tutorials](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/articles) to see that this is not very difficult.